# How to filter columns of a matrix whose IQR is below a specific value?

Tags: r, matrix, numeric, predicate, iqr

`filter <- apply(expressionMatrix, 2, function (x) (colIQRs(x, na.rm = TRUE) < 1.6))`

"Argument x is of class numeric, should be a matrix" error was thrown. How to cope with that? I think logically this code is correct: I remove all columns, whose IQR values is less than 1.6.

How to code this technically?

Comment: Please provide a data example and desirable output.

Answer (score 1):

colIQRs from package `matrixStats` requires a matrix as an input. But by wrapping it inside an `apply` statement, you are giving it only a single column vector at a time.  The solution is to send the whole matrix to colIQRs, then subset on the result:

```
filter <- expressionMatrix[, colIQRs(expressionMatrix, na.rm = TRUE) < 1.6]
```